# Effective MacOS/iOS framework for rendering custom maps (Spritekit or raw Metal)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics, metal

trying to keep this question as specific as I can to avoid being closed as too broad. My end goal is to render marine (as in nautical) maps. See image below as a reference. I've researched some of the various Apple frameworks to see what suits this best. My data input is effectively an array of arrays where each child array represents a cartographic feature (think an island or boat dock). I started w/ Core Graphics as it has a very simple API however it's performance is poor (it was taking > 100ms for a single layer of data when I can expect 10-20 layers on average).

Which brings me to my question: would SpriteKit be an effective framework for handling this workload? My preference is to avoid learning Metal but if fellow devs recommend this approach I will invest the time. SpriteKit seems to be able to handle this- I'll probably be working with a few thousand to a few hundred thousand points/vertices at a time. I dont need any complex animations as the map is static in terms of display. Any inputs appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Sprite Kit works off of Metal and should be fast enough to handle your problem here.  I have written tests to handle thousands of sprites,  iOS handled them with ease,  and this was back when iPhone 5 was still a thing.

Comment: The main implementation detail is to make sure your "interest points" render with a common texture/graphic so that a single resource is rendered multiple times in an efficient way. There should be no problem getting 60 FPS rendering performance, of course you need to implement and verify. You should also define the specific iOS hardware you are attempting to support and test properly, as opposed to just assuming that the code will just work on every hardware configuration without testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [GeoJSONMap](https://github.com/maxvol/GeoJSONMap)
>
> Build maps from GeoJSON with MapKit or SpriteKit.
>
> SpriteKit maps can be displayed offline and/or as planes in ARKit.

I loaded a city map resulting in 256 static SpriteKit nodes made from filled GeoJSON polygons, it gives me only 3.7 FPS on iPhone XS. Perhaps some optimisation is possible, but I did not try.

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to share your full code base?

Comment: This article explains the process step for step - https://medium.com/@maxim.volgin/offline-maps-with-geojsonmap-and-spritekitdsl-608d14db2cf3 If stuck, post specific piece of GeoJSON and desired effect here.